# Cannot Change Text of Label in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView which displays the address and phone number of a business. I want to use a label next to the address and phone number. For some reason, all of my labels say "Address" even though I have the phone label set as "Phone" in the storyboard and in the code. Why is it doing this?

[How it looks in the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtQNZ.png)

[How it looks when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY1NK.png)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:  "cell") as! ProfileCell

    cell.addressLabel.text = "Address:"
    cell.phoneLabel.text = "Phone:"

    cell.addressInfoLabel.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.phoneInfoLabel.text =  objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am not able to open the images.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove following lines

```
cell.addressLabel.text = "Address:"
cell.phoneLabel.text = "Phone:"
```

My guess is you have set outlet reference to `addressLabel`, what should have been referred to `phoneLabel`. Check that.
I checked your code. The problem is with height of the labels. Address label is overlapping phone label. Here are the things you can do

1. Change the background colors of the address label and phone label. You will realise that address label is completely hiding phone label.
2. Remove aspect ratios for the labels and give some constant height.e.g. 30
3. Implement heightForRow for tableView and give some height e.g. 150.

Comment: It still doesn't work. My outlets are set correctly.

Comment: OK. anyways you should remove these two lines as they are redundant and unnecessarily setting the values to already set values. If you can share the project with me I can debug.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DZI9mQkAg6eUZUQXpKS01QZ3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can I have the height of the row change somehow based on the amount of content?

Comment: self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
Set number of line in info label to zero.

Comment: That still makes the address label overlap the phone label.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7U6n3xL_VQBSTFpVWpzR3Qzck0/view?usp=sharing. I made few changes. The two labels are separated. You need to adjust things according to your need though.

Comment: It works now, but how do I make it so that the phone shows up in the phone category instead of a duplicate of the address?

Comment: Problem in your code. You are not accessing the values properly.         if objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects.count > 1 {
        cell.addressInfoLabel.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[0]
        cell.phoneInfoLabel.text =  objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[1]
        }

Comment: Last question. Is there a way to remove the second row in the tasks section as well as the "Address" label and just have one label?

Comment: Yes. First way If objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[1]  is nil, hide it.

Comment: I used your code, but it's giving me a ton of duplicates of the address and the phone number instead of creating the right amount.